# How do I use formulas to find the midpoint and other milestones between two dates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

I am trying to make a Google Sheets document for work that will contain the date someone signed, the date that the wedding is occurring, when the first and second payments are due, and when to send emails for appointments.

So if someone signed on December 7th, 2022, and their wedding is October 9th, 2023, I need to find the midpoint in between those two dates for their first payment, 4-5 months before for their first appointment, 1 month before for their second appointment, and seven days before for their final payment. I want to write a formula or function to take the signing date and wedding date and have it give me the dates for the above. I am new to Google Sheets. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's recommended to include [tag:google-sheets] in questions about Google Sheets; on the other hand, [tag:google] should not be used. This came from a discussion held in [meta]. On questions about Google Sheets please describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet including the locale / country setting as it affects how dates should be entered in cells to be handled as dates instead of text or numbers. Google Sheets is the most popular tag. Probably your question was already asked and answered.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Google Sheets are treated as numbers. A day is equal to 1, and the hours and minutes are fractions of 1. I won't extend on how are they calculated, but knowing that, you can treat them as any number:

```
=(A1+A2)/2 To find the middle point for example

=A2-7 to get the last meeting
```

And I suggest you get into other date functions. For example, EDATE will let you go x amount of months ahead or behind I'd you choose positive or negative numbers. For example, for one month prior to the date:

```
=EDATE(A2,-1)
```

I hope this insights are useful!